Auto rotate the client secrets of SPNs
I have an app registration created  and we are utilising this SPN client credentials (client id and secret) to acess the REST API of an azure resource. The SPN is used to generate a token to authenticate to the azure resource for utilsing its REST API's .
Owing to security policy its mandatory to rotate the client secret of this SPN every year, is there a way to automate this ? I couldnt find the managed identity option under the app registration. Ours is a simple shell script.

managed identity are managed service principal, you can create them as azure resource not ms entra resource.

in fact user assigned identities are azure resources. system assigned identities are created with the resource itself


Auto rotate the client secrets of SPNs

You can automate the rotation of the client secret for your Azure app registration using a combination of Azure keyvault and a shell script.
Use the below script:
#!/bin/bash

appId="xxxx"  # SPN client ID
tenantId="xxxx"
subscriptionId="xxxx"
keyVaultName="testvenkat"  
secretName="s1"
expiry="12"  

az account set --subscription $subscriptionId

# Generate a new client secret
newSecret=$(az ad app credential reset --id $appId --append --years $expiry --query password -o tsv)

if [ -z "$newSecret" ]; then
    echo "Failed to create a new client secret"
    exit 1
fi

echo "New client secret generated successfully."

# Store the new secret in Azure Key Vault (Optional)
az keyvault secret set --vault-name $keyVaultName --name $secretName --value "$newSecret"

echo "New client secret stored in Key Vault: $keyVaultName"

# Retrieve old secret IDs (not expiring soon)
oldSecretIds=$(az ad app credential list --id $appId --query "[?endDateTime<'$(date --iso-8601=seconds)'].keyId" -o tsv)

if [ -z "$oldSecretIds" ]; then
    echo "No expired or old secrets found to delete."
else
    for keyId in $oldSecretIds; do
        # Delete the old secret using its keyId
        az ad app credential delete --id $appId --key-id $keyId
        echo "Old client secret with keyId $keyId has been deleted."
    done
fi

# Output the expiration date of the new secret
expiryDate=$(az ad app credential list --id $appId --query "[?keyId=='$(az ad app credential list --id $appId --query '[0].keyId' -o tsv)'].endDateTime" -o tsv)

echo "New client secret will expire on: $expiryDate"

The above script generates a new client secret for a service principal and stores it in Azure Key Vault and checks for any old secrets that expired and deletes them.
Output:
WARNING: The output includes credentials that you must protect. Be sure that you do not include these credentials in your code or check the credentials into your source control. For more information, see https://aka.ms/azadsp-cli
New client secret generated successfully.
{
  "attributes": {
    "created": "2024-09-17T11:43:38+00:00",
    "enabled": true,
    "expires": null,
    "notBefore": null,
    "recoverableDays": 90,
    "recoveryLevel": "Recoverable+Purgeable",
    "updated": "2024-09-17T11:43:38+00:00"
  },
  "contentType": null,
  "id": "https://testvenkat.vault.azure.net/secrets/s1/decfxxxx59da324ee056",
  "kid": null,
  "managed": null,
  "name": "s1",
  "tags": {
    "file-encoding": "utf-8"
  },
  "value": "pCx8Q~eGNxxxxxm.8NiduY"
}
New client secret stored in Key Vault: testvenkat
Old client secret with keyId 9643883c-7969-46a4-a335-1f84e92e5770 has been deleted.
New client secret will expire on: 2036-09-17T11:43:35Z


You can automate this script by scheduling it to run at a specific time or interval using a cron job or Azure Logic Apps.
Reference:
Automate Azure App registration client secret rotation - Microsoft Q&A
